# Spark: create new column from another but not nullable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple problem, but can find an easy solution.

I noticed the following:

```
myDF.withColumn("newColumn", col("aNullableColumn"))
```

Then in the schema the `newColumn` is becoming nullable, even if there are no null values in `aNullableColumn`.

How to get `newColumn` to be not nullable?

I googled a little bit, the only solution I found is to rewritte the schema and recreate the dataframe, but this isn't nice solution.

Comment: What is your endgoal here? Spark won't enforce it anway.

Comment: The field `newColumn` is set as non nullable, and I want to keep it non nullable (because a mandatory one). When I change its value, I don't want its nullable property to change. I also tested something like when(col("aNullableColumn").isnull, 46).otherwise(col("aNullableColumn")) but it still becomes nullable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that your column has no `null` values, you can do this to change the nullability property of your new column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, coalesce

myDF.withColumn("newColumn", coalesce(col("aNullableColumn"), lit(0)))
```

And make sure to use correct data type inside the `lit` function (the same data type as is your `aNullableColumn`). Also be aware that if there is `null` value, the `coalesce` function will change it to the value you provide inside `lit`.

The reason why this works is the way how `coalesce` deals with `nullable` property. This is taken directly from Spark source code:

> Coalesce is nullable if all of its children are nullable, or if it has no children.

Here the second child is `lit(0)` and this is not `nullable` therefore the resulting column will not be `nullable` either.